# Apple script Clicking on button in safari not working

Tags: javascript, youtube, safari, applescript

I am trying to make a applescript that can click the "send message" button on youtube. I have tried my code in many different ways but can not get it to work.

P.S view the youtube form here:https://www.youtube.com/inbox?action_compose=1&to_user_ext_ids=lqsOL7q1W1R2N55Y7JN_7Q

Here is my code!

```
tell application "Safari"

    activate
    delay 1

    do JavaScript "document.forms['composeform']['inbox.sendMessage'].click()"

end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I paste the JavaScript code in my browser (Console in FireFox) I get the error that the requested object is not defined. In simple terms the object doesn't exists. However the button does have an element id and can be get by the getElementById function. Don't worry, an element id's value must be unique in the entire document.

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell document 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('inbox_send_message').click()"
    end tell
end tell
```